# Python - object has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, random, module

I want to import the `random` module to use `randint` and get a random number from 1 to 10. I have this so far:

```
import random  
number = random.randint(1,10)  
print number
```

I've also tried importing `randint` specifically, but that doesn't work either.   With the code above, I get `object has no attribute 'randint.'`

I've come across plenty of people getting this error. The solution has always been to find the file you've named `random.py` and change its name because the script is loading that instead of the real module. I understand that, but I can't find that file; I've searched high and low, and the only file I can find named `random.py` is the real module in the Python library list.

Comment: What does `random.__file__` show you?

Comment: Umm, it says Command not found.  I'm using 2.7 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're saying, you can import random, but it's not the random module.

If `random.__file__` works, then it's another module, and you get the path. Remove this path from your python file, or rename the file.

If it does not work (as your comment suggests), you need to investigate further. Use `type(random)`, `help(random)`, etc... to find out what it is and you should be able to get more color. See if you are importing some modules before in your workflow, in which `random` is defined.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I never did figure out what the problem was, but uninstalling and reinstalling Python did the trick, so I'm assuming I had something set up wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably using a statement too specific at the top of your file such as:

```
from random import random
```

Instead of the correct, (but more broad) statement:

```
import random
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this basic issue multiple times.  You would think I would learn by now.

You may have a file in that directory or in the path of your own making that is called "random.py"

When you go to import random from your code it steps on itself.

Comment: OP says he searched for random.py and it's only in his Python distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Add this (#!/usr/bin/python)to your top of the file save and run again.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

It will automatically add this two line below to above #!/usr/bin/python,  (FYI I am using Sublimetext3)

```
(# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```